# Como re estructurar dataframe en pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

dispongo de un dataframe que muestra información agrupada disponiendo en las columnas, en multi index, los meses del año, subagrupados por años, y en las filas los diferentes centros. Quiero desempaquetar por así decirlo el multindex para que quede una tabla mostrando como indice varias columnas.
[image: dataframe]

Esta es la tabla de la que dispongo actualmente, y lo que quiero es que el dataframe que se muestre finalmente muestre por ejemplo:

```
1/1/2017/2082949.0
1/1/2018/2204553.0
1/1/2019/2726634.0
1/1/2020/2744176.0
1/1/%/1.0
1/2/2017/1673355.0
...
...
```

En un formato semejante a ese, es decir que no agrupe a la hora de mostrar la tabla, para que así sea más facil trabajar con ella desde excel. He usado unstack() pero no consigo el formato deseado. No se como podría compartir el dataframe, si alguien lo necesita y me indica cómo yo se lo mando.

Comment: Publica tu código, un ejemplo de datos de entrada y la correspondiente salida que deseas (para chequear que hayas sido bien entenido). Está página te explica mejor como crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para eliminar un nivel puedes usar reset_index:

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df
```

(suponiendo que el DataFrame se llama df)
En caso que no lo solucione, por favor, comparte un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: con eso lo he arreglado gracias, desconocia el tema del inplace